# On what basis is the rate of Sn1 reaction dependent

Tags: nucleophilic-substitution, carbocation

Does the rate of reaction depend on the stability of the  1st carbocation formed just after the leaving group leaves or the rearranged carbocation's stability? for eg
[image]

Here if i compare the stability of initially formed carbocation then the order should be C>D>**B>A** here in B more hyperconjugation should bring about more stability hence the order which I wrote just now. But if we compare the overall stability after rearrangement of carbocation then order should be C>D>**A>B** 
please suggest what should I compare

Comment: What do you mean by "rearranged carbocation"? Also, why do you think there will be more hyperconjugation with B than with A?

Comment: In general, as a first order approximation, the rate of the reaction is dependent on the activation energy, which is often a higher lying transition state. Reactive intermediates, like carbocations, are stable structures, at least more than transition states.

Comment: @Snijderfrey Rearranged carbocation means that initially for the formation of carbocation in part (A) Cl will be removed giving a primary carbocation. This happens in both (A) and (B) so I thought more stable initial carbocation (rate determining step is formation of carbocation) will require less activation energy.

Comment: @Snijderfrey I think hyperconjugation depends on the number of "alpha" hydrogens present next to carbocation. Initially (before the carbocation (A) shifts to tertiary carbon by methyl shift) (b) has more "alpha" hydrogens than (A). And** hyperconjugation is a more  important step for determining stability than inductive effect**

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Any suggestions? for the order that I mentioned?

Comment: Hyperconjugation is not limited to C-H bonds.

Comment: yes i know but its not required here

Comment: There is reverse hyperconjugation also like in Ph-CCl3 etc

Comment: @Snijderfrey Please elaborate different types of hyperconjugation as I can recall only 2

Answer (score -1):

The rate of a S<sub>N</sub>1 reaction depends solely on the stability of the rearranged carbocation and also on the leaving group tendency. The better the leaving group, the faster will be the reaction.

Here, the correct order would be D>C>A>B.

In C, $\ce{-OCH3}$ is present which is an EWG. So, it won't stabilize the carbocation. Hence, D>C.
And between A and B, A will be a secondary carbocation whereas B will be a primary carbocation after the leaving group leaves. So, A>B.

Comment: I think in methoxy the +M effect outweighs the -I effect, especially in regard towards a cation.